# Beautiful Soup and extracting a div by ID

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the number of "confirmados" cases of COVID-19 from this page https://coronavirus.gob.mx/datos/

This is my line of code `table_div = soup.find('div', {"id": "gsPosDIV"})` but is not working, I am really neophyte with web scraping.
Which is the correct form to extract this data?

This is the html
 `<div id="gsPosDIV" class="h5 mb-0 font-weight-bold text-gray-800">47,144</div`

Comment: Can you post the `html` code?

Comment: put your code in a setTimeut and make it wait a few seconds, while the page loads

Comment: yes of course  <div id="gsPosDIV" class="h5 mb-0 font-weight-bold text-gray-800">47,144</div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is loaded dynamically via JavaScript. You can simulate the Javascript requests by `requests` module and then parse the data with `re` module:

```
import re
import requests

data = {'sPatType': 'Confirmados',
'cve': '000',
'nom': 'Nacional'}

url = 'https://coronavirus.gob.mx/datos/Overview/info/getInfo.php'

raw_data = requests.post(url, data=data).text

positivos = re.search(r'document\.getElementById\("gsPosDIV"\)\.innerHTML = \((\d+)', raw_data).group(1)
print(positivos)
```

Prints:

```
47144
```

Comment: Thank you! So when We have dynamic data, Beautiful Soup isn´t the best way to obtain the data?

Comment: @MarianaFernandez In general case no, BeautifulSoup is good for static data. But in sometimes the dynamic data returned is in HTML format, so BeautifulSoup is handy in this case.

Comment: Thank you!  :D just one more question. why the url changed?  I am sorry for the questions

Comment: @MarianaFernandez I found this URL in Firefox developer tools, Network tab (Chrome has something similar). The main page is making request to this url to obtain the info.

Comment: This is the code line for "Hospitalizados" document.getElementById("vHos").innerHTML = "39.15 %"; an I was trying to build the regular expression based on the other ones an that was my result: re.search(r'document\.getElementById\("vHos"\)\.innerHTML =  \\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?%', raw_data).group(1) but is not working and i don´t why